# Does anyone know what language this is in?

Tags: encryption, programming-languages, compression

I'm trying to understand this code (and perhaps I can port it), but I can't tell which language it's written in. If anybody would be able to give me an idea that would be great. Explaining the code would be even better, but knowing the language I might be able to figure it out myself.

```
Generate_Key_IV   proc near
      mov   eax, [ecx]
      movzx   edx, ax
      imul   edx, 9069h
      shr   eax, 10h
      add   edx, eax
      mov   eax, [ecx+4]
      push   esi                            ; Here file size
      movzx   esi, ax
      imul   esi, 4650h
      shr   eax, 10h
      add   eax, esi
      mov   [ecx], edx
      mov   [ecx+4], eax
      pop   esi
      test   edx, edx
      jnz   short loc_495EA2
      mov   dword ptr [ecx], 1
loc_495EA2:
      test   eax, eax
      jnz   short loc_495EAD
      mov   dword ptr [ecx+4], 0FFFFFFFFh
loc_495EAD:
      mov   eax, [ecx]
      shl   eax, 10h
      add   eax, [ecx+4]
      retn
Generate_Key_IV   endp
```

This is supposed to go with it (i.e. used alongside it) but I'm not sure whether it's in the same language or not:

```
int __usercall sub_47AFA0<eax>(int a1<eax>, int a2<ebp>, void *a3, size_t a4, __int64 a5)
{
  unsigned int v5; // edi@1
  unsigned int v6; // edi@3
  char v8; // [sp-1A0h] [bp-1ACh]@2
  int v9; // [sp-198h] [bp-1A4h]@1
  void *v10; // [sp-194h] [bp-1A0h]@1
  char v11; // [sp-190h] [bp-19Ch]@5
  char v12; // [sp-140h] [bp-14Ch]@5
  int v13; // [sp-40h] [bp-4Ch]@6
  void *v14; // [sp-3Ch] [bp-48h]@5
  char v15; // [sp-34h] [bp-40h]@2
  char v16; // [sp-24h] [bp-30h]@4
  unsigned int v17; // [sp-14h] [bp-20h]@1
  char *v18; // [sp-10h] [bp-1Ch]@1
  int v19; // [sp-Ch] [bp-18h]@1
  int (__cdecl *v20)(int, int); // [sp-8h] [bp-14h]@1
  signed int v21; // [sp-4h] [bp-10h]@1
  int v22; // [sp+0h] [bp-Ch]@1
  void *v23; // [sp+4h] [bp-8h]@1
  char v24; // [sp+8h] [bp-4h]@1
  int v25; // [sp+Ch] [bp+0h]@1

  v22 = a2;
  v23 = (void *)v25;
  v21 = -1;
  v20 = sub_72CCC6;
  v19 = a1;
  v18 = &v24;
  v17 = (unsigned int)&v22 ^ __security_cookie;
  v10 = a3;
  v9 = sub_5657C0(a4);
  sub_495EC0(a4 * a5, (unsigned __int64)a4 * a5 >> 32);
  v5 = 0;
  do
    *(&v15 + v5++) = Generate_Key_IV((int)&v8);                          ;Generating KEY
  while ( v5 < 0x10 );
  v6 = 0;
  do
    *(&v16 + v6++) = Generate_Key_IV((int)&v8);                          ;Generating IV
  while ( v6 < 0x10 );
  sub_47AC20(&v15, 16, &v16);                          ; AES Routine
  v21 = 0;
  sub_433E00(v9, v10, a4);
  v21 = 1;
  sub_4799F0(&v11);
  if ( v14 == &v12 + (-(signed int)&v12 & 0xF) )
    memset(v14, 0, 4 * v13);
  return __security_check_cookie((unsigned int)&v22 ^ v17);
}
```

This would be great to know, thanks!

Comment: Ask your question here: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd guess C/C++ and than decompiled... Labels do not look human written.

Comment: Well - the first is assembler code, but if it is written directly in that or it is a higher level programming language compiled into assembler, I do not know.

Comment: Second one looks like a c dialect emitted by a decompiler.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov: Ah, I forgot that that exists. Thanks a lot, I'll be sure to ask such questions there in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet is Assembly language. Refn: [click here](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html)

and second part is C language.

Comment: Thanks! That should help with figuring out what it all means.